# Generating repeated values from a column of group values

Tags: r, dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Semester = c(rep(1, each=8), rep(2, each=6), rep(3, each=5)))
```

I want to make a second column, `Student`, that for every semester, goes 1, 2, 3,... and then resets for the next semester. That is, it creates the following:

```
df <- data.frame(Semester = c(rep(1, each=8), rep(2, each=6), rep(3, each=5)),
                 Student = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
```

just from the `Semester` column. How do I do this without a `for` loop?

Comment: `dplyr::mutate(df, Student = dplyr::row_number(), .by = Semester)`. Requires dplyr >= v1.1.0; otherwise use `group_by()` instead of `.by`.